# Validation failed, creating limit order on BSC. 0x

Tags: 0x

We've tried multiple times to create a limit order (SRA) on BSC and every time receives this:

```
 {code: 100, reason: "Validation Failed", validationErrors: []}
```

Our order:

```
{
  "chainId": 56,
  "expiry": "1632584020",
  "feeRecipient": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "maker": "0xf18a3af576c7871fea9f8f3e54e8d0e71c98f206",
  "makerAmount": "100000000000000000",
  "makerToken": "0xfb288d60d3b66f9c3e231a9a39ed3f158a4269aa",
  "pool": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "salt": "1632497620289",
  "sender": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "signature": {
    "r": "0xcdd267bd8d211cfa9d45a3e0836753ad565d485fe76d238a8590f9e96371a715",
    "s": "0x6064719f3def8f2228837a3ed0a77cbf646aafb66d7f802f84d9c5a7b8cb0f39",
    "signatureType": 2,
    "v": 27
  },
  "taker": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "takerAmount": "38642859776552",
  "takerToken": "0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c",
  "takerTokenFeeAmount": "0",
  "verifyingContract": "0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff"
}
```

How can we use the limit orders on BSC and does the 0x have executors (relayers) of these orders on the BSC chain?

Looking forward,

Answer (score 0):

Yes 0x is LIVE on BSC, you need to change your API endpoint to a different server as specify [here](https://0x.org/docs/api#introduction): https://bsc.api.0x.org/

Comment: Our ERROR (request from API) now:
{code: 100, reason: "Validation Failed", validationErrors: []}

Comment: We need not 0x swap, we need SRA (limit orders) on BSC